# How to access a simple SOAP Service in Perl

Tags: perl, soap

I am currently dabbling around with perl and SOAP, using SOAP::Lite.

I have a simple SOAP server that appears to run fine:

```
#!perl -w

  use SOAP::Transport::HTTP;

  use Demo;

  # don't want to die on 'Broken pipe' or Ctrl-C
  $SIG{PIPE} = $SIG{INT} = 'IGNORE';

  my $daemon = SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Daemon
    -> new (LocalPort => 801)
    -> dispatch_to('/home/soaplite/modules')
  ;

  print "Contact to SOAP server at ", $daemon->url, "\n";
  $daemon->handle;
```

It includes a small class called Demo, which simply retrieves the systems total memory:

Demo.py

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Sys::MemInfo qw(totalmem freemem totalswap);

print "total memory: ".(&totalmem / 1024)."\n";
```

I have an example of a SOAP client below written in PERL, although I am unsure how to communicate with the server (since the [tutorial](http://guide.soaplite.com/) I am following here goes of on a tangent e.g. retrieve the result of the Demo.py class from the client:

```
  #!perl -w

  use SOAP::Lite;

  # Frontier http://www.userland.com/

  $s = SOAP::Lite 
    -> uri('/examples')
    -> on_action(sub { sprintf '"%s"', shift })
    -> proxy('http://superhonker.userland.com/')
  ;

  print $s->getStateName(SOAP::Data->name(statenum => 25))->result;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Last time I messed around with SOAP::Lite, I gave up and used plain HTTP instead. Could post here an example, if you are interested.

Comment: @Dmitry Negoda Hi Dmitry, Yes please if possible! :)

Comment: Just offhand, I think you need to specify your port in the proxy.  So it should read `->proxy('http://superhonker.userland.com:801/')`  I have a working SOAP::Lite code connecting to a .NET service.  I'll take a closer look later when I can access the code, if it isn't answered in the meantime.

Comment: Turning on the trace flags might help:  use SOAP::Lite +trace => qw(transport trace debug);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the server script, the dispatch_to method takes the path to the package to load, and the name of the package itself.  If you pass a third parameter, it will limit the names of the methods made visible by the server.  (e.g. 2 methods named `memory` and `time`, passing `Demo::time` as the 3rd param will make `memory` invisible to the client service.)

File server.pl

```
my $daemon = SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Daemon
    -> new (LocalPort => 801)
    -> dispatch_to('/home/soaplite/modules', 'Demo')
;
```

Your Demo package should be a package with methods that return the values.  I couldn't get Sys::MemInfo compiled on my system, so I just used localtime instead.  I'm not sure why you named your package Demo.py, but Perl packages must have the extension pm, otherwise they won't be properly loaded.

File Demo.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package Demo;

#use Sys::MemInfo qw(totalmem freemem totalswap);

sub memory {
    #print "total memory: ".(&totalmem / 1024)."\n";
    return "Can't load Sys::MemInfo, sorry";
}

sub time {
    my $time = localtime;
    return $time;
}

1;
```

For the client code, there's 2 important pieces that must be properly specified to work, the `proxy` and the `uri`.  The proxy is the url path to the soap web service.  Since you are running the server script as a daemon process, your path is just the  web site's url.  My computer doesn't have a url, so I used `http://localhost:801/`.  The 801 is the port you specified above.  If you were running as a cgi script inside of a different web server (such as Apache), then you would need to specify the cgi script to call (e.g. `http://localhost/cgi-bin/server.pl`, changing the package in server.pl to `SOAP::Transport::HTTP::CGI`.

`uri` is probably the most confusing, but it's the namespace of the xml files returned by the web service.  Turn on `+trace => 'debug'` to see the xml file returned by the web service.  The uri should just be the name of the server.  Even if you switch ports or to a cgi dispatch method, this uri stays the same.

File test.pl

```
#!perl -w

use SOAP::Lite +trace => 'debug';

# Frontier http://www.userland.com/

$s = SOAP::Lite->new(proxy => 'http://superhonker.userland.com:801/',
        uri => 'http://superhonker.userland.com/');
               #might be http://www.userland.com/
               #but I could not test sub-domains

print $s->time()->result;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll recycle these two answers for tips:

- [Client of web service in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586145/client-of-web-service-in-perl/5586523#5586523)
- [Remote function call using SOAP::Lite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143603/remote-function-call-using-soaplite/3144948#3144948)